# Issue while displaying field in django forms

Tags: django

I am new to django. I need to display some fields and forms based on certain conditions. I have my forms.py as

```
class ArgsForm(forms.Form):
     run_options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Default Options',  choices=(('dataQA','DataQA'),('merge','Merge')), required=False,
     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'checked' : 'checked'}))


class CharOptionForm(forms.Form):
     name = forms.CharField(label='Name', required=False)
     char_choices=(('1','CC Char',), ('0','IC Char',))
     options  = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Run Type', widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=char_choices, initial='1')


     def clean(self,request):
            data = self.cleaned_data
            if data.get('options', 1):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Match found')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Provide more data')

My view.py is
class TechnologyView(View):
    app = AutoCharEvalApp

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CharOptionForm()
        return render(request, 'autochar/charoption.html', {'form': form, 'view': self})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CharOptionForm(request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('autochar:main', args=(form,)))
```

In templates I have added

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Basically I want ArgsForm should be displayed only when options-=1 is selected Can someone please help what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of errors here.

Firstly, `clean` is only called when you call `form.is_valid()`, which you have not done. You need to do that in the view's `post` method.

Secondly, nothing will happen when you do, because you haven't passed the POST data to the form. You need to instantiate it in the `post` method with `form = CharOptionForm(request.POST)`.

Thirdly, when you do that, you will get a TypeError, because you have declared `clean` to take a second parameter, `request`, which the form is not expecting to pass to that method. You can't access the request there: instead of trying to set messages inside the form, you should be using ValidationErrors, which then display in the template in the form's `errors` attribute.

Fourth, you cannot instantiate another form and return a response inside the form's `clean` method: you need to do that in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel. I will try your suggestions. I might bother you again if it does not work. Thanks once again

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried your suggested changes still it didn't work. I have modified my post. Since I am new I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly. Can you please review or refine the code for me. Thanks

Comment: You're still not calling `form.is_valid()` in the `post` method. And the template should reference `form.errors`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will try again. Can you recommend me some good django book to start with. I have seen few over net but not sure which one to buy. I would appreciate your suggestion. Thanks